# mpiexec, without copying DLLs

Tags: dll, mpich, mpiexec

In my Windows test, I'm interested in running MPI with the localhost, without the resource-overhead of copying DLLs. I would rather use the PATH defined in the calling-environment. I've been unable to do this on the mpiexec I've been calling, even if passing "-envlist PATH" to mpiexec.

The underlying problem is such that when I call my compiled executable, I get error codes "-1073741515," which tells me I am missing dependencies. When I copy DLLs to that directory (which I'd rather not do), I get a non-error code, "0."

To test, I used a "printenv.exe" command I used. I ran it using mpiexec, to show that the PATH is not actually set in the calling environment.

I am trying to prevent copying DLLs, to instead use a PATH. Can I not pass the PATH to the called environment?

```
D:\test>d:\thirdparty\win32-msvc2010\64bit\mpich2\v1.4.1p1\bin\mpiexec.exe -exitcodes -np 1 -envlist Path "C:\Program Files\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin\printenv.exe"

...
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\mpirt;... libraries that aren't from the called PATH.
...
```

Data: I am using MPICH2, v1.4.1p2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned that this is a known bug on MPICH2, v1.4.1.

We have decided to use Intel's implementation of MPI, which does not exhibit this bug.